# how to add the html file as an attachment in python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, email, smtp

```
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('C:\Users\Desktop\ADI\New folder'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.html'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        page = filename
        #print filename

        server.quit()
```

In the above code : Firstly, I am finding the *.html files in a directory. I am finding it, it is working fine for me. Later I want to send that html file as an attached email to some person. I am failing in that. Can someone suggest me how to attach an file to the email and send it to the concerned person ?
The above program is WORKING FINE in sending the email to the person, which just prints the name of the file in the email but not able to attach that email and send it.

ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\task.py", line 39, in <module>
    server.sendmail(fromaddress,toaddress,msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\email\message.py", line 137, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\email\generator.py", line 83, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\email\generator.py", line 115, in _write
    self._write_headers(msg)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\email\generator.py", line 164, in _write_headers
    v, maxlinelen=self._maxheaderlen, header_name=h).encode()
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\email\header.py", line 410, in encode
    value = self._encode_chunks(newchunks, maxlinelen)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\email\header.py", line 370, in _encode_chunks
    _max_append(chunks, s, maxlinelen, extra)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\email\quoprimime.py", line 97, in _max_append
    L.append(s.lstrip())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to attach file content to email data.

e.g.

```
with open(fileToSend) as fp:
    attachment = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment",\
                      filename=os.path.basename(filename))

msg.attach(attachment)
```

Do following in your code(replace `msg.attach(MIMEText(text))` line with following code):

```
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
    ctype = "application/octet-stream"
maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)

with open(filename) as fp:
    attachment = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment",\
                      filename=os.path.basename(filename))

msg.attach(attachment)
```

**Note**: `filename` should be complate path of file which we want to attach in email. e.g. `/var/opt/html/report_email.html`

---

If I add multiple receiver email id then it is not working.

1. if `toaddress` is string where each email id separated by comma i.e. `,` 
   e.g. `"abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com"` then do like `server.sendmail(fromaddress,toaddress.split(','),msg.as_string())`

Comment: can you please tell me where to adapt your code in my program ?

Comment: I updated answer according to your request. `filename` should be absolute path. Let me know if any exception is coming or not.

Comment: I am getting the error as :   File ".\task.py", line 29, in <module>
    with open(filename) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'report_email.html'. The report_email.html is my file, which I want to send. I modified my code as above.

Comment: need full path of file in `filename` variable. e.g. `/var/opt/html/report_email.html` This exception raise when file is not exist on system.

Comment: filename is basname of file, so do like `filename = root.rstrip(os.sep) + os.sep+ filename`

Comment: If I add multiple receiver email id then it is not working. for example - toaddress = ['manth.v@ance.com', 'a.gper@nance.com']

Comment: we have to split into list  e.g. `["abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.come"]`

Comment: what changes you did due to which this stop working?

Comment: what is value of  `toaddress` variable ??`toaddress = 'hemanth.venkatappa@nuance.com'` ??

Comment: now I changed to : toaddress = henth.ventappa@nce.com, hemhnkappa@nce.com

server.sendmail(fromaddress,["henth.ventappa@nce.com", "hemhnkappa@nce.com"],msg.as_string()). but it is not working.

Comment: `toaddress = henth.ventappa@nce.com, hemhnkappa@nce.com ` this is tuple.  rewrite as `toaddress = "henth.ventappa@nce.com, hemhnkappa@nce.com" ` i.e. `toaddress` is `string` now

Comment: last question : how can I print the content of the html file as a message body in the email. if there are many email then how to concatenate those things as a single email. I want to print the content of the html file as a body of the email

Comment: 1. `msg.attach(MIMEText(open(filename).read(), "text/html"))`. This will show html content in the body of email.. 2. I am not get second point?

Comment: I am getting the output as <h1>Language: ENG</h1>


<table border="0">
 <colgroup>
  <col width="100"><col width="140">
 </colgroup>
 <tr>
  <td>Test Start: </td><td>2016-01-25 08:11:07</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Test End: </td><td>2016-01-25 08:16:06</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
 <tr>
but not the character within html. how to do that ?

Comment: hmmm you know have to parse html file?

Comment: I am getting in the body in the form of headers, col width and so on but not the actual character or content of it. should i parse for it ? we are reading but why is it not working ?

Comment: think we have to use BeautifulSoup. isnt it ?

Comment: its not working. can you help me ? I modified the code as import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(filename)
msg.attach(MIMEText(open(soup).read(), "text/html"))
but I am getting error as : ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

Comment: install BeautifulSoup on machine first. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I have messaged you in gmail. please answer